# "Do not nest generic types in member signatures" for a nullable decimal

Tags: c#, generics, code-analysis

I have the following interface

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    DataItem<decimal?> MyProperty { get; }
}
```

And the `DataItem` class looks something like this

```
public class DataItem<T>
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public DataItem(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

When I run code analysis I get the warning

> CA1006 Do not nest generic types in member signatures Consider a
>   design where 'IMyInterface.MyProperty ' doesn't nest generic type
>   'DataItem<decimal?>'.

In the [MDSN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182144.aspx) I am told

> Do not suppress a warning from this rule.

I am generally inclined to follow the guidelines. So how would I refactor my interface (or `DataItem` class) to follow these guidelines? Or is it more of a redesign than refactor?

Comment: Personally I would suppress in this case.  `DataItem<decimal?>` isn't really that complex.  The rule was really meant to catch something like `Dictionary<Tuple<int, string>, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>`.  I've suppressed it when the nesting is only one level deep like your case.

Comment: Remember that Code Analysis looks at the IL in the assembly not your source code. The decimal? is c# short hand for a Nullable<decimal>. So what code analysis sees is DataItem<Nullable<decimal>>. That nesting is what it is complaining about. I would be inclined to simply suppress this since this is one of those situations where code analysis is not smart enough to understand that is not what you see in the source code.

Comment: But say I really wanted to follow the guidelines. What would I need to do to adhere to the guidelines? Maybe create a `NullableDataItem<T>` class that constrains the `T` to a struct and has a `public T? Value { get; set; }` property? Or is there a better way?

Comment: *"is there a better way?"* - try to search for error code itself. There are plenty of cases with solutions: [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/417634/1997232), [click](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b26ffe68-1350-4d05-95ca-48c442a833f7/a-better-way-to-resolve-ca1006?forum=vstscode), ...