# FXCop violation for generic types

Tags: c#, asp.net, fxcop

While using `IList<Dictionary<string, string>>` as parameter type in method declaration FXCop violation occurs

> It doesnt nest generic type `IList<Dictionary<string, string>>`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: See [Are there any good workarounds for FxCop warning CA1006?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417634/are-there-any-good-workarounds-for-fxcop-warning-ca1006)

Comment: Also this [Alternative to nested type of type Expression<Func<T>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441563/alternative-to-nested-type-of-type-expressionfunct)

Comment: You can create a class containing the list, but I would ignore this rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for that is:

> A nested type argument is a type argument that is also a generic type.
>   To call a member whose signature contains a nested type argument, the
>   user must instantiate one generic type and pass this type to the
>   constructor of a second generic type. The required procedure and
>   syntax are complex and should be avoided.

It helps you to design a simpler interface. You have 3 cases:

- use [`SuppressMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx) attribute
- [remove the rule from ruleset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429303(v=vs.80).aspx)
- [try to fix violations change the design to remove the nested type argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182144.aspx)

You can try:

```
public void Method(Dictionary<string, string> param)
```

and use:

```
var list = new IList<Dictionary<string, string>>();
list.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>{{"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "value2"}});
list.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>{{"key11", "value11"}, {"key22", "value22"}});

foreach(var element in list)
{
    Method(element);
}
```